# Android worker detects Activity close condition

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a task that needs to be run regularly, every few seconds, in background. I am therefore using `m_Handler.postDelayed` (not `AsyncTask`). Each time the task completes, it kicks itself off again with another postDelayed call to re-run in a few seconds time. Correct me if I'm wrong but I didn't think it was possible to invoke an `AsyncTask` at regular intervals.

The problem is that my background task can detect a condition under which I want my Activity's UI thread to call `setResult` and then `finish()`. In other words, I want my worker thread to be able to tell the UI thread to terminate the Activity.

Is there a way for a worker thread like this to signal the UI thread to do something? Alternatively, is there a way to invoke an `AsyncTask` at regular intervals? What is the best way to run a regular task that can request the Activity to close?

Answer (score 0):

postDelayed doesn't create a background thread; it posts messages to a handler, which is usually attached to the UI thread.  So if you're using the default handler you should already be on the main thread, and able to finish the activity.  If your handler is on another thread, you could keep just post to the default handler.  Basically, if you're running from another thread in the activity, post (or postDelayed) are used to run something on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks Steve for clarifying that and debunking my misconception. I think I can now figure out a viable design.